# How to fix python pip and pip3 returning "No module named 'concurrent'" upgrading

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, upgrade, repair

Everything was working fine then I upgraded my pip now anytime I run pip I get the error. running python 3.9.2

```
pip3 install pandas
```

returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir, enum
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 38, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.tenacity import retry, stop_after_delay, wait_fixed
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from concurrent import futures
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concurrent'
```

Comment: Module `concurrent` is a module from [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/concurrent.html). Please check if you have a directory `c:\python39\lib\concurrent`; if not your Python installation seems to be broken; try to reinstall Python.